# Good source of solved exercises in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

I am taking an introductory course in functional analysis.

I am looking for a good book (or other source) with solved exercises in functional analysis, so that I can practice and check the answers to make sure my solutions are good.
Does anyone familiar with such source?

Thanks in advance!